# Get user id from reaction

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm creating a ticket system for my bot but I don't know how to get the id of the user who reacted.

Here's my code:

```
@Client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(TicketID, user):
    username = user
    message_id = TicketID
    if message_id == message_id:
        channel = await Client.create_text_channel(username + " - ticket")
```

I tried to use user for the ID but I just get this error:

```
TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you added an extra parameter to the function, which isn't there in the docs. This means Discord won't know that it has to pass in a user ID, so it won't, which will cause the error that you see.

You can use [`RawReactionActionEvent.user_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) to get the user's id.

```
@Client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    userid = payload.user_id
```